# When did the modern vegetarian movement start?

Tags: history, animal-experimentation

I know there has been vegetarians all over the world throughout history. When did the modern "Western" movement start and who began it?
I've been reading about anti-vivisection in the 1870s and I'm wondering if that is where it started or if it was only in the 70s in the US.

Answer (score 3):

One of the earliest modern western vegetarians was [Thomas Tryon (1634-1703)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Tryon). He wrote many books which were popular at the time.

More widespread vegetarianism didn't begin till the 19th century though. The poet Percy Bysshe Shelley (1792–1822) was a well known advocate. Vegetarianism was connected with the Christian temperence movement. It led to the creation of the [Vegetarian Society](http://www.ivu.org/history/england19a/bible-christian.html) in 1847 by Joseph Brotherton MP and James Simpson. This society is still in existence today.

[The American Vegetarian Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vegetarian_organizations) (modelled after the British version) was founded in 1850 by William Metcalfe, William Alcott, Russell Trall and Sylvester Graham in New York City, as a similar religious based movement spread there.

Comment: The famous writer Leo Tolstoy was also avid proponent of vegetarianism. See http://veg.ca/1998/09/07/history-of-vegetarianism-leo-tolstoy-author-of-war-and-peace/

Comment: I had no idea that the western vegetarian movement had religious bases.